# Using jQuery to read data from google sheet with column name having hyphens

Tags: jquery, google-sheets

I am trying to read data from a google sheet using jQuery. I can read well the data of a column called name1 like this:

```
this.gsx$name1.$t
```

However, another column is named as q-name2-s. It has hyphens. Following code to read the column data is failing:

```
this.gsx$q-name2-s.$t
```

It is failing because of hyphens. Please suggest some alternative. Thanks.

Comment: try `this['gsx$q-name2-s'].$t`